# In ArcPy I need code to transform M-value to coordinate X,Y

Tags: route, measurements

Input: route linear feature
M-Value as input from text box
Output: X,Y value

I need code to convert a measure value to X,Y coordinate. The measure value is an input value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please tale the [Tour]. Questions that start with "I need code" are less likely to get responses than Questions that state "Here is the code I have, but it's not working right". There are a number of contexts in which you could be working, so clearly explaining what you do have and what you have tried so far will make it easier to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ArcToolbox tool [Feature Vertices to Points](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) will create a point file that includes your M values.  [See here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011691) for more help.  [And here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) for populating the vertices table with x and y values if you need to do that as well.

You will find the relevant Python code at the bottom of each tool description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try to explain better what I need; I have a layer as route, I  give as a input to my routine a measure value and i'd like to receive as result the coordinate, similar to make route event layer but using python code without  create e measure table.

Comment: Oh, I understand.  No, I am unaware of that tool.  This Python code could be adapted to create a point at your desired distance along your line. https://github.com/LummiGIS/Create_Points_Along_A_Line_Feature_Class.  Then, get the x and y values using geometry tools in arcpy.